# Why doesn't \n or PHP_EOL produce a new line in this online PHP compiler?

Tags: php, ide

I have this very simple code:

```
<?=
  "This is great".PHP_EOL."\r\nfoobar";
?>
```

The code, however, does not insert a new line when I use the online IDE available at [PhpFiddle](http://www.phpfiddle.org), but it does work on the [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php) IDE.

The code does, however, do what I want and produce 2 new lines on PhpFiddle if I wrap the code with html tags.

What is the difference in the implementation of these two IDEs?

Comment: because it's html. html doesn't care about line breaks. they're considered whitespace, no different than a normal space. if you want a line break in html, you have to use `<br />`. if it works in one editor, then that editor is taking steps to render with `<pre>` tags, or using `nl2br()` or whatever to make them ACT like actual line breaks.

Comment: never trust what your browser is showing you. its job is to translate pretty much anything it can into what it THINKS you want. when debugging/developing, that's always going to be the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was confused as to why the one compiler was printing a new line when it really shouldn't have.

What should I use instead of the browser when debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What good is new line character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554566/what-good-is-new-line-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently mixing up 2 things:

1. HTML output
2. CLI output

The `\r\n`  characters are only correctly displayed when you run your PHP script in [`CLI` mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

As, I would say, 99% use PHP for Web Applications these characters are ignored. Use instead the HTML tags. For example `<br />` for a new line.

Comment: So would you say that TutorialsPoint is running in CLI mode?

Comment: @TomJacob You can see, in the link which you provided in your question to TutorialsPoint, there is an open terminal device window and your sample code is executed by `php main.php` and this is the CLI mode - see the link in my answer. AND, the `HTML` code is printed 1:1 - without any rendering!

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a line break using HTML, you must use the `<br />` tag so that your browser recognizes and renders the line break.  Using the carriage-return and newline (`\r\n`) is treated as whitespace and becomes rendered as such (a space) rather than a new line.

Answer (score 0):

To see the text in new line try to use `<br/>` instead of `"\n"`. In HTML only one white space is read. others are removed.